# simple php include single htm file safety

Tags: php, html, include

I use this in htm file to include another htm file

```
<?php include("media/android.htm"); ?>
```

Is this safe?

Both of them are simple htm file with text and pictures.

Comment: ask this question to yourself as included file is located on your local server. and ouput of php is also html.

Comment: What kind of safety are you talking about. I cant see a thing that is required to be secured.

Comment: I asked myself, but there's a weird silence

Comment: I know that the included files could be somehow switched with the bad ones and they could be run to hack a website

Comment: But why would someone hack a website which simply contains text and pictures.

Comment: Security of text and pictures on a website doesn't make sense. Thus the question is inappropriate

Comment: Thank you, Gottlieb Notschnabel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's completely safe. That's how PHP works.

But, keep in mind that's a php file, not html.

Answer (score 0):

use jquery to load a file

```
$("#div1").load("media/android.htm");
```

Comment: I dont think that this was asked by the OP.

Comment: @vascowhite he wants to load a file in php we can go for include but in  html no include . can you tell best solution ?

Comment: There is no best solution. The way you include the file depends on the your requirements

Comment: if there is no best solution then giving suggestions is better I think

Answer (score 0):

Try this
include file without php